# EasyPost prefetch price

Tags: easypost

I am trying to fix a price using USPS and Easypost API. However, in my case based on weight I wanted to show the user list of pricing (Rates) from Easypost. And later when the order comes in, the rate would be used for posting to the recipient.

I do not have the to_address at this point, I just have from_address and possibly weight of the product to create parcel object.

My query is can we get price list without to address? And if so, how should we do it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this via EasyPost. All you need is the origin and destination zip code to fetch USPS rates from EasyPost. If you are building an eCommerce website, for example, you could ask the customer to enter their zip code before checkout to estimate shipping costs. Rating with zip codes can be done via the `/shipments` endpoint https://www.easypost.com/docs/api#create-a-shipment

Another option is to ship with a USPS Flat Rate box. If you know that you can always ship items in a "small flat rate box" for example, then you know that you can ship for $7.90 (regular pricing for EasyPost customers) to anywhere in the United States. You can see the full rate chart at https://www.easypost.com/usps-rate-chart.